# How can I send a java list with object to ajax get as response?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, ajaxform

How can I send a java list with object to ajax get as response?

My spring controller code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get/patient/by/name/{search}", produces = "application/json", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
List<HasAppointment> getpatient(@PathVariable("search") String search) {
    System.out.println(search);
    List<HasAppointment> list = hasAppointmentRepository.findbyLikefirstname(muds.getUser().getIdUser(), search + "%");
    return list;
}
```

This is my Ajax code:

```
$("#search-appointment").keyup(function () {
    var search = $(this).val();
  //  console.log(search);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/get/patient/by/name/"+search,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',

        complete: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the issue/error ?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Comment: Please enclose your method inside a try/catch block. `List<HasAppointment> list = new ArrayList<HasAppointment>(); try {list = hasAppointmentRepository.findbyLikefirstname(muds.getUser().getIdUser(), search + "%");}catch(Exception ex){ System.out.println(ex);} return list`. This will help validate the issue is in the find method or elsewhere and that you are returning a response (empty list) correctly.

Comment: I try it but  I still have the same error

Comment: Please share the exception in the question. It will help others to find the point of error. If the empty list is not making through then the issue lies somewhere else.

Comment: at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.beanserializerbase.serializefields(beanserializerbase.java:740) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]

Comment: my problem was resolved by adding    @JsonBackReference on LIST<HasAppointment> in model